# “A mutual friend”, "A common friend" or “A friend in common”?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

When I was a student of EFL, I was taught the word "mutual" implies a reciprocal relationship where X does to Y what Y does to X.  If John admires Peter as much as Peter admires John, we can say their admiration is mutual.  That said, can I say that Charles and I have a mutual friend ?

Comment: "Charles and I have a friend in common" sounds most natural, and perhaps most informal, to me. "Mutual friend" works too but I've only heard it used in cases like "Alice is a mutual friend of Charles and I", as in @brasshat answer.

Comment: @seismatica 'of Charles and I' is a hypercorrection. I'm not sure how 'acceptable' it is (or who decides).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  When former president Bill Clinton said during a speech in his presidential campaign that "My mother was busy raising my brother and I", the Mainstream Media didn't ignore it and teachers of English were eager to criticize.

Comment: But BBC News announcers adopted the practice of using 'I' with expressions like 'It's goodnight from John and I' for a time. [Patricia O'Conner and Stewart Kellerman](http://www.nytimes.com/2009/02/24/opinion/24oconner.html?ref=opinion) write 'For centuries, it was perfectly acceptable to use either “I” or “me” as the object of a verb or preposition, especially after “and.” Literature is full of examples. Here’s Shakespeare, in “The Merchant of Venice”: “All debts are cleared between you and I.”' But I agree, I wouldn't use 'I'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the following source the expression *mutual friend*, despite language critics objections, is commonly  used and accepted.

[Mutual](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Mutual): Usage Note,

> Mutual is used to describe a reciprocal relationship between two or more people or things. Thus their mutual animosity means "their animosity for each other" or "the animosity between them," and a mutual defense treaty is one in which each party agrees to come to the defense of the other. *But many people also use mutual to mean "shared in common,"* as in The bill serves the mutual interests of management and labor. *This usage is perhaps most familiar in the expression our mutual friend, which was widespread even before Charles Dickens used it as the title of a novel.* While some language critics have objected to this usage because it does not include the notion of reciprocity, **it appears in the writing of some of our greatest authors, including Shakespeare, Edmund Burke, George Eliot, and James Joyce, and it continues to be used by well-respected writers today.**

Also [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20mutual%20friend%2Ca%20common%20friend%2C%20a%20friend%20in%20common&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20mutual%20friend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20common%20friend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20friend%20in%20common%3B%2Cc0) shows a more common use of the expression *usual friends* compared to the other two suggested alternatives.

Source: The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you and Charles are both friends with Alice, you can refer to Alice as a mutual friend. This allows an implication that you are a friend of Alice, and Peter is a friend of Alice, but you are not necessarily a friend of Peter.

The designation "a common friend" means nearly the same, but has a small risk that someone might wonder if there is a better friend who is better than just common, as in "Eddie is a common friend, but John is in a class by himself."

Answer (score 0):

Odd you should choose the name “Charles” for your example; for though purists may agree with your teacher, Mr. Charles Dickens, with his last completed novel, opened the floodgates to the usage *[[Our] Mutual Friend](http://www.gutenberg.org/etext/883)* beyond possibility of shutting.

Comment: [Dickens isn't responsible](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=our+mutual+friend%2COur+Mutual+Friend&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cour%20mutual%20friend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2COur%20Mutual%20Friend%3B%2Cc0); the phrase was around long before his book.

Comment: @Peter But surely not at flood level?