# Which of these two words is proper in denoting a friend?

Tags: word-choice

"Our mutual friend" or "our common friend" - which is more suitable ? Why is that so ?

Comment: Take a look at this ELU question: [“A mutual friend”, “A common friend” or “A friend in common”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184787/a-mutual-friend-a-common-friend-or-a-friend-in-common).

Answer (score 0):

A mutual friend is someone both people know. 
A common friend is someone who isn't very selective. Using 'common' with friends seems very offensive. 
'Mutual friend' is the more appropriate way to put it.

Comment: There is some truth in what you say, but the uncouth sense of 'common' influences the many other senses only by connotation. 'Common soldier' is not considered derogatory. And 'Fanfare for the Common Man' (Copland; after Wallace) was given that title as a tribute. (Copland: "I [am] all for honoring the common man at income tax time" [when the piece was premiered]) brasshat implies (in an answer to the original) that the risk of someone being offended by 'common friend' is small.